# How to set active menu on layout?

Tags: jquery

So i have layout and in layout i have navigation.

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a id="whats-on" href="/index#whatson">WHATS' ON</a></li>
        <li><a href="/visiting-us">VISITING US</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">COLLECTIONS & RESARCH</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">LEARNING</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">GET INVOLVED</a></li>

        <li><button class="search" id="search"><img src="images/loupe.png" /></button></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I tried this jquery :

```
$(function() {
     var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href
.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
     $("nav ul a").each(function(){
          if($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '' )
          $(this).addClass("active");
     })
});
```

But problem is that when page is refresh active menu is lost. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like following. Hope this helps.

```
$(function() {
 var pgurl = window.location.href;
 $("nav ul li a").each(function(){
      if(pgurl.indexOf($(this).attr("href"))>-1)
          $(this).addClass("active");
 })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Replace

```
$("nav ul a").each(function()
```

with

```
$("nav ul li a").each(function()
```

Hope this helps...